# JPA's Sort object with attributes in different table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl, spring-repositories

TL;DR

The question is:

- Is there a way to order a query in one table in regards to an attribute of a different table?

Keep reading for more context

---

In my project I have the following abstract class `QueryParams`:

```java
public abstract class QueryParams {
    public static final int DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER = 0;
    public static final int DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 50;

    private String sort;
    private int page = DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER;
    private int size = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;

    public abstract Sort getSorting();
    public abstract BooleanBuilder getPredicate();

    public Pageable getPageable() {
        Sort sorting = getSorting();
        if (Objects.isNull(sorting)) {
            return PageRequest.of(getPage(), getSize());
        }
        return PageRequest.of(getPage(), getSize(), sorting);
    }
}
```

We extend this class for different entities, so we use the power of QueryDSL to create complex pageable queries. Here's our usage:

```java
entityRepository.findAll(entityQueryParams.getPredicate(), entityQueryParams.getPageable());
```

The problem arises when I want to sort a query according to a column from a different table.
We have a specific entity that holds the ID and TYPE of other entities (no direct relationship) and I'd like to sort the results by the other table's `name` column.

The `Sort` object is usually created like so:

```java
@Override
public Sort getSorting() {
    QEntity qEntity = QEntity.qEntity;
    return Sort.by(ASC, qEntity.name.getMetadata().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is, you can join the association in your JPQL query and then sort by any column on that entity.

In QueryDSL one can do:

```java
select(QEntity.entity).from(QEntity.entity)
   .innerJoin(QEntity.entity.association, QAssociation.association)
   .orderBy(QAssociation.association.attribute)
```

Your custom `QueryParams` class needs to be extended to support different query roots.

Comment: So my usage would need to be changed, as it appears I can't rely on the `Sort` object to achieve this, right?